Getting SQL error in DBeaver connecting to Cassandra "NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query"
There is a problem with working with Cassandra in DBeaver.
Cassandra 4.0.12
Cassandra JDBC Driver 4.9.0
After executing a simple Select query (SELECT * FROM tbl_file), an error occurs:
SQL Error: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query

I configured the driver for Cassandra, the test connection worked without errors


How to solve this problem?
SQL request will work without errors.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

I am able to replicate the issue you described by not specifying a fully qualified JDBC URL:
jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042

If I try to list the contents of any table, I get:
SQL Error: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.struct.JDBCTable.readData(JDBCTable.java:192)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:194)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:5147)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query
    at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:353)
    at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraStatement.execute(CassandraStatement.java:360)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:330)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:131)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException.copy(NoNodeAvailableException.java:40)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:53)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:54)
    at com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:347)
    ... 10 more

According to ING's driver usage guidelines, you need to provide both a default keyspace as well as the local DC in the URL:


JDBC driver class: com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver
JDBC URL: jdbc:cassandra://host1--host2--host3:9042/keyspace?localdatacenter=DC1


I am able to browse the contents of table when I update the JDBC URL used by the Cassandra connection to include a default keyspace and local DC. For example:
jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042/communityks?localdatacenter=datacenter1

As a side note, version 4.9.0 of the ING Cassandra JDBC wrapper was released over a year ago (April 2023). If you upgrade to the latest (version 4.12.0 at the time of writing) and test the connection using a URL which does not have the local DC specified, the driver will report an error explicitly stating that you must specify the local DC. Here's an example error:
Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set \
  (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it \
  programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: \
  Node(endPoint=localhost/<unresolved>:9042, hostId=1d382a19-635f-4a4a-acb8-68aeba8b3648, hashCode=46f4eeff)=datacenter1. \
  Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1

I would recommend using the latest version of the driver. Cheers!

To complete the Erick Ramirez’s answer, since the version 4.12.0, it’s also possible to specify the load balancing policy DcInferringLoadBalancingPolicy like this: jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042/communityks?loadBalancing=DcInferringLoadBalancingPolicy without specifying a local datacenter.
